# Prove $\sum \frac{\sin(n^2 t)}{n^2}$ converges

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ be a Banach space and a sequence $(x_n) \subseteq X$ be such that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \|x_n\|$ converges in $\mathbb R$.

Prove that the sequence $S_n=x_1+\cdots+x_n$ converges in $(X,\|\cdot\|)$. (This is the first part so assume that it is true)

(i) Prove that the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(n^2 t)}{n^2}$$ converges for each $t \in [0,1]$

(ii) Let $$f(t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(n^2 t)}{n^2}$$ Prove that this function $f$ is a continuous function on $[0,1]$. (Use first part)

For (i), let $$a_n= \frac{\sin (n^2 t)}{n^2} \leq \frac1{n^2},  \, \, \forall t$$ and we know $$\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac1{n^2}$$ converges so our original sum converges by the comparison test. Is this correct?

For (ii) I am unsure. What exactly do i have to prove?

Comment: @ClementC. for (i), are you saying $a_n=\sin(n^2 t)/n^2 = |\sin (n^2 t)/n^2| \leq 1/n^2$? So it converges absolutely?

Comment: I converted my comment in answer. Basically, you want uniform convergence, i.e. $\sup_{t\in[0,1]} \lvert \sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{\sin n^2 t}{n^2}\rvert \xrightarrow[N\to\infty]{} 0$. But the above implies normal convergence, which is even stronger.

Comment: @ClementC. I see... Also for part (i), do you want me to say $ A_n= \sum |\sin(n^2t)/n^2|$ converges since $|\sin(n^2t)/n^2| \leq 1/n^2 $, and $\sum1/n^2$ converges so $A_n$ converges so $\sum \sin(n^2t)/n^2 $ converges absolutely. Is this OK?

Comment: You probably should phrase it, to kill two birds in one stone, along these lines: the series $A_n(t) = \sum_n a_n(t)$ converges (pointwise, and even uniformly on $[0,1]$)) since it converges normally, as the series $\sum_n \sup_{t\in [0,1]}\lvert a_n(t)\rvert$ is convergent (by comparison, as $\sup_{t\in [0,1]}\lvert a_n(t)\rvert \leq \frac{1}{n^2}$. But then, (ii) follows as you have just established that you have a series of continuous functions, that converges uniformly.

Comment: @ClementC. In the question, where i wrote "(use first part)", this didn't mean (i), it meant that the sum of the partial sums converge ($S_n$). Is there a way that we can use this to answer (ii)?

Comment: @ClementC. Because I don't think we have come across these uniform related stuff yet...

Comment: Mmh. You mean you haven't seen the theorem about the uniform limit of continuous functions being continuous? Without this, it sounds rather trickier.

Comment: @ClementC. Yeah just doubled checked my notes, not much on continuity. Our lectured said that this was a tricky question...

Comment: In that case... the brute-force (not intended, I assume) approach would be to re-prove this theorem from scratch, then apply it. Or you could try to do a spacial case by considering $\lvert f(t+h)-f(t) \rvert \leq \sum_n \frac{1}{n^2} \lvert \sin(n^2(t+h)) - \sin(n^2 t)\rvert$ and trying to bound that with something going to $0$ when $h\to 0$ using trigonometric identities. (There may very well be is a much more elegant or completely different way, though.)

Comment: @ClementC. For something like this series function is continuous, what exactly do we have to prove? As in what is the end result that we have to show?

Comment: That for any fixed $t>0$, $f(t+h) \xrightarrow[h\to0]{} f(t)$. (It's the usual definition of continuity, but since $f$ is defined by an infinite series it's a tad harder to do 'manually,' i.e. without using nice theorems like the one mentioned above.)

Comment: @ClementC. what if we take out f(t) at a arbitrary point, say n and then prove it is continuous. So we have proved $f_n(t)$ is continuous at any point of $n$ so $f(t)=f_1(t)+f_2(t)+...+f_n(t)+...$ should also be continuous by the agebra of continuous functions (which is something we used last year so I'm sure we can use it this year). Is this dumb or is it going somewhere??

Comment: It is not actually true, because of the infinite sum. But it is true of the series converges *uniformly* on some open interval containing $t$...

Comment: @ClementC. But in (i) we proved that it converges for $t \in [0,1]$, is this not the same as converges "uniformly"?

Comment: No. Check the definitions of uniform convergence given above (in a link). Uniform convergence (on an interval $I$) is stronger: $\sup_{t\in I} \lvert \sum_{n=N}^\infty f_n(t) \rvert \xrightarrow[N\to\infty]{} 0$. (Pointwise convergence at $t_0$ would be only on the trivial interval $I=\{t_0\}$.)

Comment: @ClementC. cant we somehow use the fact that $S_n=x_1+x_2+...$ converges... there must be a decently nice way to do this...

Comment: Without using the concept of uniform convergence (let along normal convergence)? There may be a way, but I can't see any elegant one.

Answer (score 1):

For (i), use that the series converges absolutely since $\lvert \sin n^2t\rvert \leq 1$, as you did.

For (ii), show [uniform convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence) of the series on $[0,1]$ (follows from the proof for (i), where you basically prove [*normal* convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_convergence), which implies uniform), so that you can argue that [the *uniform* limit of a sequence of *continuous* functions is itself continuous.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#To_continuity) (Note that the hypothesis of uniform convergence is necessary, pointwise convergence is not enough in general.)

Comment: for (i), are you saying $a_n=\sin(n^2 t)/n^2 = |\sin (n^2 t)/n^2| \leq 1/n^2$? So it converges absolutely?

Comment: Basically, to apply the theorem for (ii) you want uniform convergence, i.e. $\sup_{t\in[0,1]} \lvert \sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{\sin n^2 t}{n^2}\rvert \xrightarrow[N\to\infty]{} 0$. But the above (what you wrote) implies normal convergence, which is even stronger: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sup_{t\in[0,1]} \lvert \frac{\sin n^2 t}{n^2}\rvert $ converges.